# How do you resize a bitmap image in layer-list on Android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, bitmap

I am following this procedure to create a splash screen -> https://medium.com/@shishirthedev/the-right-way-to-implement-a-splash-screen-in-android-acae0e52949a

It works fine, but the bitmap is quite big, I would like to resize it smaller and keep the high definition. This here below is the result, I would just like to have a centred small app logo in the center. How do I achieve that?

That's what I got:

[image]

That's what I want:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_colour"  />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/icon_okay"
            android:gravity="center"
        />
    </item> </layer-list>
```

Comment: How about use a smaller image, or change the drawable location of your current image?

Comment: I used a smaller image resulting in a very poor quality image. Unfortunately only .png are allowed and not .svg files. What do you mean with changing location? thanks

Comment: I mean you can change the image file directory from, for example, drawable-xhdpi to   drawable-hdpi. You can try to change the location and pick a suitable one. I have ever tried to add this kind of image to splash page, you can visit my open source project https://github.com/Shouheng88/MarkNote for help.